# How would I automate video editing using variables?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, image, audio

I'm going to be honest with you. I'm trash at python. I need help automating the video sequencer. How would I go about making a script that can open a picture and a sound file from a path?

Lets say I have a folder called "DOG". Inside of that folder are two more called DOG.sound and DOG.image. Inside of those folders is a sound and an image.

Is there any way that I could not only set up a variable system that inserts the sound and image based on the variable, but then also change the length of the image, change the audio volume, add fade with cross and color strips, etc.? This seems like it would be a little much. I need it to open a .blend, find an image and a sound file, set the length and channel, set the timeline to end 10 seconds after the sound ends, set a cross to fade in and out, and then render to a directory. Am I trying to do too much?

Comment: In one of my answers I posted just that... Has been a while, though.

Comment: Not a coder myself, but it sounds quite fasible with the correct knowledge of the Python API. This seems however like a very broad question in the infamous "do it for me" style. What have you got so far? What have you already tried and where did it fail?

Comment: You're right, that is in a "do it for me" style. Umm... I don't know the syntax or commands for the VSE and don't see any guides. I've tried copying the output from the info window, but it doesn't have the parameters I need. Really if I could just figure out how to make a text entry in Blender that allows me to put the name of the variable in, then I could dig for more information on the other stuff.